# If ViewController is embedded in TabBarController, some of the content is not tappable

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, orientation

I have a test project and created ViewController which is embedded in TabBarController. I've placed 'UISearchBar' and 'UISegmentedControl' with constraints and in portrait mode they are clickable. But when I rotate to landscape mode(iPhone) only 320 pixels of the searchBar and segmentedControl is clickable, the rest isn't. This is better explained in the figures below.

Why is this happening?

How should I "stretch" the clickable area in landscape mode?

As you can see the constraints are working fine, the components have their correct sizes.

[image: Figure 1][image: Figure 2]

Comment: Here is my test project. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67542609/TestConstraints.zip

Comment: I've just checked your project, but you're view hierarchy is not as simple as stated in the question! The view as shown in the screenshots are not directly on the main view, but they're all placed in a subview of a UITableView (why?). You need to adjust the constraints for all superviews, to get it to work, however I'm not sure what you're trying to do there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just put the following code in mine TabBarViewController class.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    // fix for iOS7 bug in UITabBarController
    self.selectedViewController.view.superview.frame = self.view.bounds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of your constraints are working fine, but very likely others are not. If the segmented control is only partially tappable in landscape, you should check the frame sizes for it's superview(s).

It looks like in landscape mode the segmented control is partially outside the superview frame. If the superview frame is ok, look further into the superview hierarchy.

To fix it, try this:

- Select all the components in IB (search bar + segmented control + date picker)
- Open menu 'Editor' -> 'Resolve Auto Layout Issues' -> 'Reset to Suggested Constraints'

Comment: I've just double checked the frames and they're fine. You can see from the screenshots that the frames are correct because the superview's components are stretching to its edges.

Comment: I've just tested your case, but works fine with me, so i think it is a constraint issue. To resolve this check my updated answer.

Comment: Well, I've tried that, bit still no improvement. I need to place them in a UITableView because that's satisfying my need/logic.

Comment: Never mind my structure, even though I place only one segment control in a TabBarController with leading and trailing constraints the result is the same :S WEIRD!

Comment: Did you notice it works correctly when switching to the other tab and then switch back? Btw you're not calling `[super viewDidLoad]`, but that didn't solve the issue. Weird indeed. I'll look into it later.

Comment: Yes i know :D I found a very stupid workaround in the tabBarController's didRotate method i put this:
 [self setSelectedIndex:1];
 [self setSelectedIndex:0];